# Can Ackerman set theory without class construction scheme plus a limitation of size axiom prove consistency of ZF?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Take all axioms of [Ackermann's set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory), remove the class construction axiom schema.

Add the **limitation of size** axiom:

$\forall X \forall Y [X \in V \land Y \subseteq V \land |Y|\leq |X| \to Y \in V]$

> Would the resulting theory prove $V$ to be a model of $\sf ZF$?